# Violacion de segmento en Nasm con Debian

Tags: debian, ensamblador, base64, gcc, nasm

Hice este Hello world con Nasm .. y estoy intentando llamar funciones de C mediante libc .. pero el programa me tira "violacion de segmento"

```
; Filename:libc.nasm
; author:me



 extern  printf
 extern  exit

global main



section .text

 main:

    push message
    call printf
    add esp, 0x4 ; adjust the stack

    mov eax, 0xa
    call exit

     section .data

    message: db 'hello world', 0xA, 0x00
    mlen     equ $-message
```

Asi lo compile:

```
 nasm -f elf64 -o  $1.o $1.nasm



 gcc  -o libc libc.o
```

Comment: En linux mint, pero en arquitectura de 32 bits pude compilar y hacer funcionar perfectamente tu ejemplo si te sirve el dato. Debieras pegar el mensaje de error. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias ..ya lo solucione ..

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO:

nasm -f elf -o  $1.o $1.nasm

gcc -m32  -o $1 $1.o

Comment: En x86_64 los argumentos van en registros (rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9), no en la pila, por si quieres compilar para 64 bits.

Comment: Hola... disculpa ...no entiendo ... creia que la pila era solamente en esp en el caso de 32 bits...

Comment: En x86-64, en vez de pasar los argumentos en la pila (con `push message`), se pasan los 6 primeros en registros (`mov rdi, message`).